# What version of bulma supports the class table-container

Tags: vue.js, bulma

What version of bulma supports the class table-container? Can't find this in web.
(the lowest one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`table-container` is added in version `0.7.0` in `13.4.2018`. But it is added in colors, functions, mixins, and variables tables in version [0.7.2](https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/commit/57808aebab00799ee1695e97f64192e354a117d9)

Comment: `table-container` was added in 0.7.0. The documentation implemented it itself in 0.7.2, which is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

`table-container` was added in [this commit](https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/commit/b4c31c073231ef025bd02a10429221316eec2f78) and was available from
[Version 0.7.0](https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/releases/tag/0.7.0).